# Paypal integration - Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request does not

Tags: paypal, prestashop

Trying to get login with PayPal into prestashop, all seem to be done corectly accorting to installation guide but getting this error:

> Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request
>   does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the
>   request.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two modes for any application on Paypal developers website (i.e. Live and Sandbox mode), please confirm that you are using the same API data that you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, taking all data from live mode of the app.